# sql query - filtering duplicate values to create report

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to list all the duplicate records in a table. This table does not have a Primary Key and has been specifically created only for creating a report to list out duplicates. It comprises of both unique and duplicate values.

The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT [OfficeCD]

      ,[NewID]
      ,[Year]
      ,[Type]
  FROM [Test].[dbo].[Duplicates]

  GROUP BY [OfficeCD]

       ,[NewID]
      ,[Year]
      ,[Type]
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This works right and gives me all the duplicates - that is the number of times it occurs.

But I want to display all the values in my report of all the columns. How can I do that without querying for each record separately?

For example:

Each table has 10 fields and [NewID] is the field which is occuring multiple times.I need to create a report with all the data in all the fields where newID has been duplicated.

Please help. 
Thank you.

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? You've tagget the question MySQL, but you're using SQL Server style brackets where I'd expect to see MySQL style backticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable 
WHERE NewID IN (
  SELECT NewID FROM yourtable
  GROUP BY OfficeCD,NewID,Year,Type
  HAVING Count(*)>1
)
```

Additionally you might want to check your tags: You tagged `mysql`, but the Syntax lets me think you mean sql-server

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Duplicates] WHERE NewID IN 
(
    SELECT [NewID] FROM [Duplicates] GROUP BY [NewID] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select d.*
from Duplicates d
inner join (
    select NewID
    from Duplicates
    group by NewID
    having COUNT(*) > 1
) dd on d.NewID = dd.NewID
```